# Boot Repair always fails -- unmet dependencies shim-signed

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, grub2, boot-repair

Apologies in advance if I do not provide complete information -- this is my first time posting here and I'm not sure what the protocol is.

I'm running Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 in a computer lab I manage at a university. I've been having trouble getting the computers to dual boot properly, sometimes resulting in the grub menu breaking. This time I tried to run Boot Repair off a live USB, and I got to the step where it asked me to put this into the terminal:

```
sudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/sdb2" apt-get install -y grub-efi-amd64-signed shim-signed linux-headers-generic linux-signed-generic
```

However, this results in the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 shim-signed : Depends: shim (= 0.8-0ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

This happens nearly every time I try to use Boot Repair. As a result, I've been re-installing Ubuntu. However, the software my faculty uses takes about 20 minutes to reinstall, so you can imagine that this turns into a very lengthy process.

Does anyone have any guidance for how to proceed from here and get Boot Repair to work?

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT:** Here is a pastebin link: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/w47GrNgFDP/

Comment: Boot with a live USB, install boot-repair on it, run boot-repair and post the report link into your question.

Comment: And if it fails in the Live environment as well file a bug against boot-repair about missing dependencies.